# Android audio processing library to do real-time polyphonic pitch detection

Tags: android, library, audio

I'm trying to do real-time polyphonic pitch detection in Android similar to the "Simply Piano" app.
I need to process audio with low latency, apply operations on it like Constant Q Transform and then feed it to a tflite model and provide visual feedback to the user based on the analysis.
Could someone please recommend a library for real-time audio processing in android. I'd prefer a free library or something that offers a trial until the app is deployed.

Comment: Great! Could you please also add whether you want an open source or gratis library, or if not what your budget is? Thanks!

Comment: I edited the title, feel free to edit it further if you want.